# Inline HAML Links but with content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, haml

I am trying to output something along the lines of

```
<p>Hello, this is my text. <a href="#">Link here</a> This is more text</p>
```

but using HAML

How would this be done? I keep finding examples but none that show how to do it but with plain text either side of the link?

Neil

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to do a 1 liner:

```
%p= "Hello, this is my text. #{link_to 'Link here', '#'} This is more text".html_safe
```

Multiline

```
%p 
  Hello, this is my text. 
  = link_to 'Link here', '#'
  This is more text
```

Comment: Just tried this:

    %p= "This is my text #{ link_to "See ALL albums", albums_path }"

But that just outputs

This is my text <a href="/albums">See ALL albums</a>

How would I solve this?

Comment: add html_safe to the end (changed in the answer)

Comment: %p= "This is my text #{ link_to "See ALL albums", albums_path }".html_safe

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to do this:

```
%p Hello, this is my text. <a href="#">Link here</a> This is more text
```

This would work too:

```
%p
  Hello, this is my test.
  %a{:href => '#'} Link here
  This is more text
```